# To convert Long integer value into date

Tags: android

I am downloading some JSON data from a web service. In this JSON i get the Date values like "Date=1423131814.0"

This is the Date/Time on which the image is getting uploaded. Now, I need to get the original Date/Time from above returned number.
and then I also need to display the hour only same as Facebook, like 5 hrs ago, yesterday at 2:30 PM.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Return date in specified format.
 * @param milliSeconds Date in milliseconds
 * @param dateFormat Date format 
 * @return String representing date in specified format
 */
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
{
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
     return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

And invoke this method as `getDate(millis, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS")`